# C# Running batch file with arguments using UseShellExecute read the content instead executing it

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a batch file with arguments and also redirect the output.
When I don't redirect the output and use UseShellExecute = true, the batch file runs with the arguments as expected.

When I use UseShellExecute = false (to do the redirect), then I see that the command-line opens for a split a second and then closes.
I've read the output, using string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 
 and I see that it contains the batch file content...

Can someone help me understand why it happens?

Thank you for your help :)
Here's the relevant code:

```
       System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

        // the command
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = command;
        // the parameters of the command
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;


        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        try
        {
            // in case there is missing '"'
            if (isContainQuote && index < 0)
            {
                str = "missing '\"' in the command " + commandStr;
            }
            else
            {
                proc.Start();
                string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                if (bWaitForExit)
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit(m_SHELL_CMD_TIMEOUT);
                    str = "Succeed to run the command: " + commandStr + ", Output: " + proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                }
                else
                {
                    str = "Succeed to run the command: " + commandStr;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            str = e.Message + ". Failed to run the command: " + commandStr;
            // return the error from the operation system
        }
```

Comment: You don't show the cmd and args so it's halr to tell what you're trying to do. Apart from that, this info might be helpful: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553307/process-does-not-redirect-result-of-shellexecute-into-redirected-file

Comment: @TonPlooij
I would like to run the following:
loadtestrunner.bat -s"Use Cases" -c"WS_ScreenSharing_servicePrefix" -PWcsEndpoint=http://10.134.87.80 -PConferenceDuration=40 -PWCSInternalEndpoint=http://10.134.87.80 -PWCSWSEndpoint=ws://10.134.87.80:80/ -PScreenSharingFramesDirectory=C:\\SoapUInewInstall\\screensharing\\ -PScopiaNumberPrefix=64567 -PUsersPerWeb_Conference=3 -PScopiaName=SoapUItest -PScopiaServiceType=80 -PUserCount=10 -l"LoadTest 1" C:\\SoapUInewInstall\\wcs_traffic_tool\\WCS-TRAFFIC-TOOL.xml

The command is: loadtestrunner.bat
The arguments are all the rest of the command above

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your batch file could help.  By default batch files echo their commands to standard out.

Try adding an `@ECHO OFF` command to the beginning of the batch file to be sure that the batch file commands aren't echoed to the standard output.